# Python: Find indices which are *not* contained in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list of lists that contain indices, e.g.,

```py
[[ 1955 16898 15202 18603]
 [ 7758 14357 13451 18447]
 [12883 13453 14576 14604]
 ..., 
 [  954 17712  1196  1250]
 [17712   859   954 18962]
 [  954   859 17712  1250]]
```

all ranging from `0` to `21000`. Some entries will occur more than once, but what I'd like to know: Which indices between `0` and `21000` are *not* contained in that list?

The lists can be large, so efficiency matters.

Comment: Can you elaborate with maybe a smaller test example? Are you looking for the **values** not contained in the lists?

Comment: Language to use? Also, as M4rtini said - you need to be a bit more specific.  There are probably at least a dozen ways to do what you want.  So you need to tells us a bit more. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off you should use numpy. Then you can use `setdiff1d` and `flatten`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(your_list_of_lists)

np.setdiff1d(np.arange(21000), a.flatten())
```

EDIT:

To avoid copying the input twice you could flatten the array with `ravel`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ravel(your_list_of_lists)

np.setdiff1d(np.arange(21000), a)
```

Comment: I guess I could recreate the same with Python's own `set`s, but numpy is just as fine.

Comment: The arguments should also be the other way around.

Comment: numpy is more efficient on large arrays though.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer Why would you reverse the arguments?

Comment: The task is to find the indices between `0` and `21000` which aren't in `a`.

Comment: You're right, will fix that

Comment: This solution seems to copy input twice - at array creation and then, while flattening. This makes memory requirements unnecessary dependent on the input size.

Answer (score 2):

For sure, `numpy` is really fast when working with huge amount of data. However, I just want to provide a native approach using Python's [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) since there might be environments where additional modules are not a allowed (e.g. due to security issues).

For further explanation please see comments in code:

```
# sample list containing some numbers from 0 to 10
# 0, 9 and 10 are missing and need to be found
l = [
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8],
    ]

# flatten/merge sublists
merged = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

# convert list to set
s = set(merged)

# define a set containing all numbers of the desired range
interval = set([i for i in range(0,11)])

# get the difference of both sets
# the difference are the elements which are missing
missing = interval.difference(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Constant memory, linear time, no dependencies:

```
def missing(ll):
    present = [False for _ in range(21000 + 1)]

    for l in ll:
        for n in l:
            present[n] = True

    return [n for n, is_present in enumerate(present) if not is_present]
```